# I cannot delete the rows using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
$('#DepartmentNameDropdown').change(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "http://localhost:8081/crownregency/getInfoSearch.php",
        data: {id: $('#DepartmentNameDropdown').val()},
        success: function(data){
                $("tbody #tbody").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    $row = "<tr><td>" +data[i]['fname']+ "</td><td>" +data[i]['lname']+ "</td><td>" +data[i]['job']+ "</td><td>" +data[i]['loc']+ "</td></tr>";
                    $('#usersTable').find("tbody").after($row);
                }

            }
        });                                          
    });
```

this is my jquery for display, when i change the departmentnamedropdown value i want to clear the table but leave the thead intact.

```
<table width="581" border="1" id="usersTable">
<thead>
    <th width="25%">First Name</td>
    <th width="25%">Last Name</td>
    <th width="25%">Job Title</td>
  <th width="25%">Location</td>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="#tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

this is my table, can someone help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is looking for an element with `id="tbody"` inside the `tbody` element. Remove the space:

```
$("tbody#tbody")
```

The id should be unique in the page, so you should be able to use just:

```
$("#tbody")
```

Comment: I did what you said but it still doesnt remove the tr under tbody

Comment: The `#` should be removed from the `id` in the HTML too - otherwise the selector would be `#\\#tbody` or `tbody#\\#tbody`

Answer (score 0):

change

`<tbody id="#tbody"></tbody>`

to

`<tbody id="tbody"></tbody>   <!-- remove the # sign-->`

and change the jQuery to:

`$("#tbody").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();`